# Multiple roles being allowed for one command with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How would I go about making it so that an admin or moderator could clear a Discord chat?

```
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def addrole(ctx, rol='member'):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name=rol)
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`commands.has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role) check instead.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:

> if role_id(admin etc.) in [role.id for role in ctx.messsage.author.roles]:

Comment: That's more or less what `has_any_role` does under the hood.  The only difference is whether you prefer to handle the rejection scenario in your main callback or an error handler.  Source: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/215fed831c0093569640ea24ff21594938908ecc/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1535

Comment: I prefer only, because i can modify it and I don't need give much lines in code